# Failing to associate an icon to a custom MIME type

Tags: files, icons, mime-types

I'm failing to add a custom icon to a custom MIME type file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've followed several tutorials in here and on other websites.

First I created a xml file called `org.xml` in `/usr/share/mime/packages`. My file looks like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
    <mime-type type="text/org">
        <comment>Emacs Org-mode File</comment>
        <comment xml:lang="fr">Fichier Emacs Org-mode</comment>
        <glob pattern="*.org"/>
        <icon name="org-icon"/>
        <alias type="text/org"/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then I updated the MIME database with the command :

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

The MIME type association is working and my Org files are detected as `text/org` but they still have a default file icon.

So I created a 512×512 custom icon and named it `org-icon.png`.

```
sudo xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 512 --mode system org-icon.png org-icon
```

This succesfully copy the icon to `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/512x512/mimetypes` although the icon file seems corrupted and I can't open it using an image viewer. I get the error message : `Failed to open input stream for file`.

After that I tried to execute :

```
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache --ignore-theme-index /usr/share/icons/
```

But nothing changed it doesn't work. My org files still have the default file icon.

What am I doing wrong ? Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to accomplish what I wanted. So I won't accept this answer since it didn't solve my original issue but I'll wait for another answer.

---

First of all I deleted all changes that I made in `/usr/share/mime` and `/usr/share/icons/` and decided to do it user-wide instead of system-wide.

So I copied my `org.xml` file into : `~/.local/share/mime/packages` then installed my icon using :

```
xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 512 --mode user --theme Adwaita org-icon.png org-icon
```

**I used the `--theme` option to install the icon in the correct theme folder, the one that I'm currently using (in my case *Adwaita*) otherwise it won't work.**
Besides my icon wasn't corrupted anymore and I could open it in an image viewer.

And finally I update the icons cache :

```
gtk-update-icon-cache --ignore-theme-index ~/.local/share/icons/
```

This way it worked and I could see my custom icon for my custom MIME type.